# Easier way to transform multiple lists into a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Right now, I have this very clunky dictionary:

```
input_data = {'names': 'Elizabeth,Emily,Grant', 'titles': 'Sales,Accounting,Operations'}

nameList = input_data['names'].split(',')
titleList = input_data['titles'].split(',')

d1 = dict()
d2 = dict() 

for val in nameList: 
    d1.setdefault('Name', []).append(val) 

for val in titleList: 
    d2.setdefault('Title', []).append(val)

fullDict = dict(d1, **d2)
```

I'm convinced there's a better way to covert this:

```
{'names': 'Elizabeth,Emily,Grant', 'titles': 'Sales,Accounting,Operations'}
```

Into this:

```
{'Name': ['Elizabeth', 'Emily', 'Grant'],
 'Title': ['Sales', 'Accounting', 'Operations']}
```

Answer (score 0):

This simple dictionary comprehension seemed to produce the result you wanted.

```
{x: y.split(',') for x, y in input_data.items()}
```

If the name part is also important, then I think this should work.

```
{x.title()[:-1] if x[-1] == 's' else x.title(): y.split(',') for x, y in input_data.items()}
```

Comment: This runs slowly and I can't figure out why. Looks neat though.

Comment: @patmcb I believe it's just because of the iteration. It'd probably do better with a larger scale compared to individually setting. Either way, it's fast enough to not really be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to accomplish two things: Split the values in the original dictionary, and rename the keys in the original dictionary. You can do everything in-place, as opposed to creating new dictionaries.

```
input_data = {'names': 'Elizabeth,Emily,Grant', 'titles': 'Sales,Accounting,Operations'}

input_data['Name'] = input_data['names'].split(',')
input_data['Title'] = input_data['titles'].split(',')
del input_data['names'], input_data['titles']
print(input_data)
```

Returns the output:

```
{'Name': ['Elizabeth', 'Emily', 'Grant'], 'Title': ['Sales', 'Accounting', 'Operations']}
```